# Word Automation Service BatchGetSyncJobStatus fails when requesting security token

Tags: sharepoint-2013, word-automation-service

I'm running a SharePoint 2013 on-premise server on which I have deployed a simple WCF service as a farm solution. The service accepts simple Http post requests that contain single MS Word documents as payload and returns these files converted into PDFs.
The service is accessible via Http to anonymous users. The WordAutomationService is running as Administration user account of the SharePoint server.

The service class creates an new instance of the Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.Conversions.SyncConverter and passes the proxy of the SharePoint's running WordAutomationService into the constructor (together with some ConversionJobSettings). Finally it calls the Convert method on the SyncConverter with the input stream (the Word document) and output stream (the web response which will contain the resulting PDF document produced by the WordAutomationService).

When creating the SyncConverter I don't set the UserToken property because the access to the service is by anonymous users. According to the remarks here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.word.server.conversions.syncconverter.usertoken.aspx this seems to be fine:

> The default value for this property is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic), which is anonymous.

This setup works fine for small Word documents with a couple of pages and returns the expected PDF files. But as soon as the execution time of the WordAutomationService on the SharePoint exceeds a certain time threshold (around 5 seconds) the service fails because it never returns (which leads to a read timeout on the client).
According to the logs it seems the reason for this is that after some time the synchronous conversion job moves the work into a background process:

> Sync Stream job conversion takes too long. Don't wait anymore. Check its status later

It then polls the status of this job on a regular basis by calling ConversionServiceApplicationProxy.BatchGetSyncJobStatus. Unfortunately this call fails because internally it tries to create a new channel to talk to this process and for that asks for a security token. The SecurityTokenService however cannot complete the token request and throws an exception:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred. The security token request cannot be completed. System.InvalidOperationException: The security token request cannot be completed.    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForServiceContext(Uri contextUri)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChannelFactoryOperations.InternalCreateChannelActingAsLoggedOnUser[TChannel](ChannelFactory`1 factory, EndpointAddress address, Uri via)     
at Microsoft.Office.ConversionServices.Service.ConfigChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address)     
at Microsoft.Office.ConversionServices.Service.ConversionServiceApplicationProxy.GetChannel(Uri uri)     
at Microsoft.Office.ConversionServices.Service.ConversionServiceApplicationProxy.ExecuteOnChannel(Uri endpointAddress, Action`1 action)     
at Microsoft.Office.ConversionServices.Service.ConversionServiceApplicationProxy.BatchGetSyncJobStatus(ICollection`1 ucids, Uri endpointAddress)     
at Microsoft.Office.ConversionServices.Service.BatchGetStatusPollingThread.Run()     
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() StackTrace:  
at onetnative.dll: (sig=37460b31-4453-4365-92f5-3a11c267be48|2|onetnative.pdb, offset=28F56) at onetnative.dll: (offset=15735)
```

I'm at a loss now how to get rid of the token issue so that the system can create the necessary channel to poll the conversion job status. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

(I can't post the full log because it registers as spam)

Comment: I can offer an AWS CloudFormation template which produces an environment with the same error: Windows Server 2012 R2, SharePoint 2013 Standard, custom WCF. So far there is no applicable solution and I have verified that the system is in en-US locale.

Comment: Arthur - Since you’ve come back to this post can you share whether you’ve made some progress

Comment: Evadne, we are currently in the process of switching to another solution without Sharepoint, therefore our Ops are not willing to invest much more time into the Sharepoint setup. I'll report back if I had the possibility to try your proposal with the application pool identity but I can't promise anything at the moment.

Comment: Which solution? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ve found that, if you were to install SharePoint 2013 on a Domain Controller (a topology that Microsoft said is only good for development but not for production), then the default anonymous user in IIS (IUSR) will not work reliably, and any WCF solution which is accessed via an IIS site that has Anonymous Access configured to use the `IUSR` account will fail when it attempts to access Security Token Service.

In this case the most expedient solution is to reconfigure IIS to use another anonymous identity, namely the identity tied to the Application Pool.

For example if your site is called `NameOfSite`, you can run this in an elevated PowerShell:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty `
  -Filter /system.WebServer/security/authentication/AnonymousAuthentication `
  -Name username `
  -Value "" `
  -location "NameOfSite"
```

This solves the immediate problem at hand which is that `SecurityTokenForServiceContext` fails. However, if you’ve installed SharePoint 2013 on Windows 2012 R2 as a Domain Controller, then it is not over: `WordServerWorker` actually will not start in this configuration.

I can also confirm, however, that if you were to install SharePoint 2013 on a standalone server (with `<Setting Id="SERVERROLE" Value="SINGLESERVER"/>` role in the unattended config file), then the entire solution works end-to-end, and WordServerWorker will actually start properly.

Previously, the most relevant (and unanswered) question on this must be this MSDN posting, [“The security token request cannot be completed”](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4aa9de9-ea70-4bb0-8450-b7d24820bd5e/the-security-token-request-cannot-be-completed?forum=sharepointdevelopment). I would assume that in that case, the service was only in a meta-stable state, and one of the IIS workers would have previously obtained credentials via NTLM during local testing.

Comment: Its should be secured for a good reason - maybe opening it to everyone even in some limited scope  is not such a good idea from secutiry point of view

Comment: Thanks for your investigation, Evadne Wu!

Answer (score 0):

Usually when sharepoint service applications interact with each other, these services maintaining current user context trough wcf calls by using [service application framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536537(v=office.14).aspx) (SAF). Its allows these services to use `SPContext.Current`, preserve correlation id between call in logs and so on. When this context is lost, services stopping being able to communicate each other. For example this happens if we have a code that starts a new thread but didn't setup user for newly created thread context.

According to your description your service is anonymous and didn't use SAF to maintain user context, but uses some services that requires existence of that context

The possible solution would be is to use SAF(which is tricky configured WCF in a nutshell) instead of plain WCF services with no authentication

**Edit:**

One more possible solution may be is wrap your code with `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` to make your services connects sharepoint with application pool identity

Comment: We are using the Sharepoint server only as the means to convert Word files into PDFs because it seems there doesn't exist any other production ready product which could do this so that the result looks exactly as if done by MS Word itself. Most/all other third party products or libraries are not able to handle all possible cases. Therefore we call our WCF service on Sharepoint from a Java application on another (unrelated) server. We don't want to persist anything on Sharepoint. Both servers are in a closed internal network, therefore anonymous access would be fine.

Comment: I have also investigated the possibility of simply sticking a reverse proxy which speaks NTLM in front of the lone SharePoint instance, but it was more complicated than it needed to be.

Comment: (Also, unfortunately, RunWithElevatedPrivileges does not fix the problem in my testing)